# React: Unable to access information from webAPI in HTTP format (WebApi return type IHttpActionResult)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I acccessed WEBAPI using React. I successfully received data (Status code 200) but in http format.
I want to extract information from this. Could you please help on this.
**IHttpActionResult** is the return type in ASP.net

Output in Postman looks like following :  [{Name: "Ravi", City:"HYD"},{Name: "Raj", City:"ABC"},{Name: "Rakesh", City:"ZZZ"}] but in react it shows totally different as shown in black screenshot.

ASP.net sample code:

```
public IHttpActionResult itemList(PropertyModel pObj)
{
    // some code.
    // returning data in list like [{Name:'a',city:'HYD'},{Name:'b',city:'HYD'}]
}
```

Output in react native when access WebAPI:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following is the piece of code I written.

```
fetch('http://IPADDRESS/Inventory/api/ItemList', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'no-cors',
          credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
          redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
          referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
          headers: {              
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
          Organisatio:'ABC',
      Type:'Item'        
          })
          }).then((response) => { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
           })
          .then((responseJson) => {        

          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
```